# how to autopopulate a column based on another column

Tags: sharepoint

I have a column name "work code" with choices off/work/leave and another column name "transport Refund" with choices none/refund. If I choose OFF in work code I need to have automatically a "NONE" in Transport refund column.
How can I do it

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below into a script editor web part into new/edit form page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select[title='work code']").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="off"){
            $("select[title='transport Refund']").val("none");
        }else{
            $("select[title='transport Refund']").val("");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]